# Why my animation isn't starting?

Tags: android, multithreading, animation, view, handler

Sorry guys, new here.

The problem is:

I have a drawable which rotates when the application tries to fetch some data from a RESTFul servive.

In onCreate() method of the MainActvity it works fine, But, when the AssycTask class cant get the data , a message is sent to the handlers waiting for the sync, then a Handler().postDelayed() is called with the method that resets the animation and update the gui. The UI is updated but animation dont start again.

Some Code:

OnCreate() runs Ok:

```
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_view);
    animation.setRepeatCount(1000);
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
    navHeaderLilCategoria.setAnimation(animation);
    animation.start();
```

anim/rotateview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
/>
```

Handler receiving message from the AssyncTask trying to connect the server, its in a singleton controlling the app. If cant fetch data, set the UI to a no connection state, then schedule a new try with postDelayed():

```
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(msg.what == ResourceManagerStatusTypes.OPERATION_OK || msg.what == ResourceManagerStatusTypes.GETTING_DONE)
        {
            triesToGetVinculoAtivo=0;
            rootActivity.updateVinculoChanged((Vinculo) msg.obj, false);
        }else{
            triesToGetVinculoAtivo++;
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    rootActivity.updateVinculoChanged(null,true);
                    vinculosManager.getVinculoAtivoPopulated(new HandlerForVinculoAtivoPopulated(false));
                }
            },MILLIS_FOR_EACH_TRY_TO_GET_VINCULO_ATIVO*triesToGetVinculoAtivo);
            rootActivity.updateVinculoChanged(vinculosManager.getVinculoAtivo(),false);
        }
    }
```

The method that updates the UI which is inside the header of a NavigationView:

```
public void updateVinculoChanged(Vinculo vinculoAtivo, boolean syncAgain) {
    navHeaderLilCategoria.clearAnimation();
    if(!syncAgain) {
        if (vinculoAtivo != null) {
            Imovel currentImovel = vinculoAtivo.getImovel();
            if (currentImovel != null) {
                String categoria = currentImovel.getCategoria();
                if (categoria == null || categoria.trim().equals("")) {
                    navHeaderImvCategoria.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_error_icon);
                } else if (categoria.equals(getString(R.string.imovel_categoria_residencial))) {
                    navHeaderImvCategoria.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_home);
                } else if (categoria.equals(getString(R.string.imovel_categoria_comercial))) {
                    navHeaderImvCategoria.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_commerce);
                } else {
                    navHeaderImvCategoria.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_industry);
                }
                if (vinculoAtivo.getDocType() == Vinculo.CPF)
                    navHeaderTxvDocumento.setText(FrazoUtils.maskToCPF(vinculoAtivo.getDocumento(), this));
                else if (vinculoAtivo.getDocType() == Vinculo.CNPJ) {
                    navHeaderTxvDocumento.setText(FrazoUtils.maskToCNPJ(vinculoAtivo.getDocumento(), this));
                } else {
                    navHeaderTxvDocumento.setText(vinculoAtivo.getDocumento());
                }
                navHeaderTxvMatricula.setText(String.valueOf(vinculoAtivo.getMatricula()));
                navHeaderTxvNome.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
                navHeaderTxvNome.setText(currentImovel.getNome());
                navHeaderTxvNome.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
                navHeaderTxvEndereco.setText(FrazoUtils.extractEnderecoFromImovel(currentImovel));
                navigationView.getMenu().setGroupEnabled(R.id.nav_menu_grp_com_matricula,true);
            } else {
                navHeaderImvCategoria.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_no_conection);
                if (vinculoAtivo.getDocType() == Vinculo.CPF)
                    navHeaderTxvDocumento.setText(FrazoUtils.maskToCPF(vinculoAtivo.getDocumento(), this));
                else if (vinculoAtivo.getDocType() == Vinculo.CNPJ) {
                    navHeaderTxvDocumento.setText(FrazoUtils.maskToCNPJ(vinculoAtivo.getDocumento(), this));
                } else {
                    navHeaderTxvDocumento.setText(vinculoAtivo.getDocumento());
                }
                navHeaderTxvMatricula.setText(String.valueOf(vinculoAtivo.getMatricula()));
                navHeaderTxvNome.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red));
                navHeaderTxvNome.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.no_conection));
                navHeaderTxvEndereco.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red));
                navHeaderTxvEndereco.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.no_conection));
                navigationView.getMenu().setGroupEnabled(R.id.nav_menu_grp_com_matricula,false);
            }
        } else {
            navHeaderImvCategoria.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_error_icon);
            navHeaderTxvDocumento.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.ative_um_vinculo));
            navHeaderTxvMatricula.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.sem_dados));
            navHeaderTxvNome.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
            navHeaderTxvNome.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.sem_dados));
            navHeaderTxvEndereco.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
            navHeaderTxvEndereco.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.sem_dados));
            navigationView.getMenu().setGroupEnabled(R.id.nav_menu_grp_com_matricula,false);
        }
    }else
    {
        navHeaderImvCategoria.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_sync);
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_view);
        animation.setRepeatCount(1000);
        animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        navHeaderLilCategoria.setAnimation(animation);
        animation.startNow();
        navHeaderTxvDocumento.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.sincronizando));
        navHeaderTxvMatricula.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.sincronizando));
        navHeaderTxvNome.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
        navHeaderTxvNome.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.sincronizando));
        navHeaderTxvEndereco.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
        navHeaderTxvEndereco.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.sincronizando));
        navigationView.getMenu().setGroupEnabled(R.id.nav_menu_grp_com_matricula,false);
    }
}
```

Sorry for bad english, and for bad coding, pls help me...

Maybe useful info:
Its only one activity running on the app, i just change a layout inside that activity, to clarify, i call the following methods:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == R.id.nav_menu_vinculos)
    {
        if(currentViewId!=R.layout.layout_vinculos) {
            changeCurrentView(R.layout.layout_vinculos,new VinculosViewController(this));
        }
    }
    if(id == R.id.nav_2_via)
    {
        if(currentViewId!=R.layout.layout_list_vinculos_row) {
            changeCurrentView(R.layout.layout_list_vinculos_row,null);
        }
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

And:

```
public ViewGroup changeCurrentView(int newViewId, GUIController guiController)
{
    removeGoneInvisible(currentView);
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootChangeableLayout);
    rootChangeableLayout.removeView(currentView);
    currentViewId = newViewId;
    currentView = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(newViewId, null);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    rootChangeableLayout.addView(currentView, params);
    if(guiController!=null) {
        guiController.control(currentView);
    }
    rootChangeableLayout.invalidate();
    return currentView;
}
```

Comment: Is your handler using the main thread? Probably you are trying to update the UI from different thread?

Comment: Its on main thread...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your below code to **onResume()**

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_view);
animation.setRepeatCount(1000);
animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
navHeaderLilCategoria.setAnimation(animation);
animation.start();
```

Comment: Btw, i never pause the MainActivity or instantiate a new actvity, i just replace the active layout which sits on the center of layout, i dont think this method wil be called but i will try.